# IndexError: index XX is out of bounds for axis 0 with size XX

Tags: python

```
for t in range(0,N):
    index = 1 + np.mod(2 ** (J - 1) * t, N)
    ind.append(index)
Gup = np.conjugate(G[ind])
```

Above piece of code gives me following error:

```
IndexError: index 302537 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 302537
```

Where N=302537
G is an array of length 302537
ind is list of length 302537
J = 6

```
G = array([1. -2.98372438e-16j, 1. -8.33750848e-05j, 0.99999999-1.66750169e-04j, ..., 0.99999997+2.50125252e-04j, 0.99999999+1.66750169e-04j, 1. +8.33750848e-05j])
```

ind = [1, 65, 129, 193, 257, 321, 385, 449, 513, 577, 641, 705, 769, 833, 897,....]

both are of length 302537 and the last element of ind is 302474

The error occurs at the last line where I am trying to calculate the conjugate.
I have tried running the loop till N-1 but that also gives the same error.Can someone help me figure out the error.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: G = array([1.        -2.98372438e-16j, 1.        -8.33750848e-05j,
       0.99999999-1.66750169e-04j, ..., 0.99999997+2.50125252e-04j,
       0.99999999+1.66750169e-04j, 1.        +8.33750848e-05j])


ind = [1,
 65,
 129,
 193,
 257,
 321,
 385,
 449,
 513,
 577,
 641,
 705,
 769,
 833,
 897,....]

Comment: both are of length 302537 and the last element of ind is 302474

Comment: With 302537 items in your array, is this _really_ a minimal example?

Comment: The error indicates that some element in `ind` is `302537` yet the size of your array is `302537`.  Remember that you can only access up to index `302536` so there's something wrong with the way you are generating the indices or you are generating them and not accounting for this index.  This is most likely due to you adding `1` in your calculations when finding the indices.  The last element being `302474` is irrelevant.  Somewhere, at least one of the elements exceeds the size of the array.

Comment: The actual error occurs at G[ind]. When passing the list to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line `index = 1 + np.mod(2 ** (J - 1) * t, N)`. The largest value of the modulo is `N-1`, but then you add one to it, so the largest value of `index` is `N`. There is no element number `N` in an `N`-element array. The largest permissible index is `N-1`. You should not add 1 to the modulo.